# How to call an another phone after hangup the first?

Tags: asterisk, voip

I would like to call a phone, hangup and call an another phone from the server.
Like this :
Server->Phone A->Hangup->Server->phone B

This is what I already tried :

```
[appel]
exten => a,1,Answer
[do something]
exten => 2,1,Goto(pasCharge)

[pasCharge]
exten => [do something]
exten => ce,2,Dial(SIP/vincent)
exten => [doSomething]
exten => ce,3,Hangup
```

I have the first call (appel) but not the second (centre). It just hangup after the first.

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want dialplan be able continue after hangup of first call, you shoudl add **g** option to dial param

```
 pro-sip.net> core show application Dial 
  -= Info about application 'Dial' =- 
   .....

[Syntax]
Dial(Technology/Resource[&Technology2/Resource2[&...]][,timeout[,options[,URL]]])
    ....
    g: Proceed with dialplan execution at the next priority in the current
    extension if the destination channel hangs up.
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on what @arheops was saying, adding the lowercase *g* in the Dial() command instructs Asterisk that when the called party hangs up, [continue to execute commands in the current context at the next priority.](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Application_Dial)

So you could do something like this:

```
[pasCharge]
exten => ce,2,Dial(SIP/vincent,g)
exten => ce,3,Dial(SIP/Vbourdon,g)
exten => ce,4,[doSomething]
```

This would dial vincent then Vbourdon, and your doSomething could be a Goto, etc, anything you like.